Trigonometry book that complements "A Course of Pure Mathematics" by G.H. Hardy.
While there are countless threads suggesting books on Trigonometry, there are none that complement the style of Hardy's book. What I mean is:
a) The style being more illustrative of what is going on under the hood rather than throwing random formulae at the reader with no common chain of thought.
$\star$ b) Lack of intriguing and challenging problems. I couldn't find any that at least remotely came close to being of the same style of problems featured in Hardy's book. This is mainly the reason I am asking the community for help.
Are there any such texts that offer problems of such caliber while also showing trigonometric applications like trigonometric optimization problems, difficult limits and offer a narrative of mostly standard trigonometric topics(elementary or not)?
I was in a hunt for looking at trigonometric books of the same era but I am yet to pinpoint any (well, except the Hobson's treatise but it lacks a few too many topics in my opinion). So any post-Hardy tripos book anyone knows of?

Of the books I know about, Hobson's book comes closest to what you want, but it's so well-known that you probably know about it already. Information about Hobson's book and three other "non-standard" trigonometry books is in my answer to Good book on advanced trig.

I am open to closing this question if no other book than Hobson's comes up, i do know about it but was hoping for something better.
